# Where is link path info generated from?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.2, core-plot

When I compile my iPhone application I get lots of errors, but the one that looks the most obvious to me is this link error:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Users/username/Documents/iPhone/MyAppName/../../core-plot/framework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator' following -L not found
```

I *know* the above path is wrong.

The correct path is:

```
/Users/username/Documents/iPhone/MyAppName/../core-plot/framework/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

I'd love to point to the right location, but I have no clue where this wrong path info is coming from. 
I have looked at every field in Project Settings and Target Settings but they're correct because they use "../" instead of "../../"
Any suggestions on where I can correct this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of itself if you've correctly configured your project. Follow the [core-plot project instructions](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications#iPhone,_iPod_Touch,_and/or_iPad_Application) on using CorePlot in an iPhone app, which are [illustrated with screenshots here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application).

In short:

- Drag the Core Plot project file into your project's group browser.
- Drag the library that will show up as a child of the project file under the "Link Binaries with Libraries" build phase for your application's build target.
- Update the Header Search Path in your application's build configuration to include the Core Plot headers.
- Add `-ObjC` to the Other Linker Flags application build configuration setting.

Comment: Fantastic! That cleared up a lot of the issues I've been seeing!